# Explicit solution to linear stochastic differential equation (in several dimensions)

Tags: calculus, probability, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I have found many references where they provide with a "explicit" solution of the following SDE:
$$dX_t = (a_1(t) X_t + a_2(t) )dt + (b_1(t) X_t + b_2(t))dB_t, \quad X_0=x, \quad (1)$$
where $B$ is a standard Brownian motion.

It is namely given by
$$X_t = \Phi_t \left(x + \int_0^t (a_2(s) - b_1(s)b_2(s)) \Phi_s^{-1} ds+ \int_0^t b_2(s)\Phi_s^{-1} dB_s \right)$$
where
\begin{align}
\Phi_t = \exp \left\{\int_0^t \left(a_1(s)-\frac{1}{2}b_1(s)^2 \right)ds + \int_0^t b_1(s)dB_s\right\}. \quad (2)
\end{align}

Nevertheless, in several dimensions it might not be possible to find a close explicit solution of the homogeneous SDE and hence expression (2) does not make sense.

Can we solve Equation (1) when $a_1,a_2,b_1$ and $b_2$ are square matrices? In exactly the same way by just defining $\Phi_t$ the solution to $d\Phi_t = a_1(t)\Phi_1 dt + b_1(t) \Phi_t dB_t$, $\Phi_0=Id$? I found this link http://math.uni-heidelberg.de/studinfo/reiss/sode-lecture.pdf (page 26) for the case $b_1(t)=0$.

Does anyone know any references on this?
Thanks!

Comment: Fixed link: http://www.math.hu-berlin.de/~mreiss/sode-lecture.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible, I found the following reference:

https://books.google.no/books?id=XjNLshgxpxUC&dq=multidimensional+linear+stochastic+differential+equations&hl=no&source=gbs_navlinks_s

page 101.